# How do I extract the minima from a list of NMinimize outputs in a smart way?

Tags: list-manipulation, mathematical-optimization, conditional

I am trying to find the absolute minimum of a potential surface on the x-y plane as a function of a third parameter p which changes the shape of this surface. In other words: at p=1, I want the position (x,y) of the absolute minimum on the surface; then, go to p=2 and do the same, and so on for a range of p.

Now comes the tricky part. The function defining my potential surface is complicated and has several minima. I suppose one could do what I need with one specialized use of `NMinimize` per p, but it takes long and still then it often gets the wrong minimum with most methods. I am open to suggestions, but I think I have found a way:
I split up my plane, e.g. y>0 & y<0, and let `NMinimize` look for the minimum on either side (this works well as long as I roughly know where the minima are localized). Then I compare the two minima I obtain and extract the coordinates of the absolute one. And this for every p.

This is a simplified version. Ideally, for each p I want to split up the plane in multiple regions and compare the various (>2) minima I obtain, and then extract the position of the absolute one. With just two minima I guess an If-construction could do the job; with more than two, it gets tricky. I was wondering whether there is a smart way to go about this. Thanks in advance!

PS: I can describe my best attempt so far. It works, but it takes way too long and is rather cumbersome.

I will need to compute the local minima on all regions for all p either way, so I do so separately and create lists with the output of `NMinimize/FindMinimum ({value at minimum, {x->x-value,y->y-value}})`. These lists we will call `list@region1, list@region2...` Then I apply `MapThread[Min,{list@region1[[All,1]],list@region2[[All,1]],...}]` to obtain a list of the absolute minima, AbsoluteMinimaList. My last step consists in checking whether `AbsoluteMinimaList[[p]] == list@region1[[p,1]]` for a p. If yes, `Reap` and `Sow` to extract the (x,y)-values for that minimum, which are stored in `list@region1[[p,2]]`; if not, check whether `AbsoluteMinimaList[[p]] == list@region2[[p,1]]`, `Reap` and `Sow` there and so on.

Comment: I'm finding it hard to understand what you need because your question is wandering between ideas. You could illustrate with a picture maybe and ask a concise question. NMinimize already tries to find the global minimum - you should use a different `Method` option maybe if you're having problems with it. Does the surface change dramatically from p=n to p=n+1 ? If it doesn't change too much, the minimum location from the previous search could inform the next one as the initial guess in a nested procedure.

Comment: Hi. I agree, my question is not exactly to the point - I do thank you for trying though. I did manage to solve my problem in a wholly different manner (to the point where my solution hardly relates to the above method). But for the sake of completion, let me say that you have a point: if one were able to use the information on the minimum at p=n, it should make the search for the minimum at p=n+1 easier.